# Check if element in array is equal to element in other array

Tags: javascript

I want to check whether `value` and `interval` values in one array are equal to another and I need new array **of values that weren't equal**, this is how I do it:

```js
let values = [{
    id: 1,
    value: 2,
    interval: 15
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 10,
    interval: 11
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    value: 2,
    interval: 12
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    value: 2,
    interval: 33
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    value: 33,
    interval: 11
  }
];

let originalValues = [{
    id: 1,
    value: 2,
    interval: 10
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 10,
    interval: 11
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    value: 12,
    interval: 12
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    value: 2,
    interval: 12
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    value: 33,
    interval: 13
  }
];
let data = values.concat(originalValues)
  .filter((val, i, arr) => {
    return arr.findIndex((v) => v.interval === val.interval || v.value === val.value) === i;
  });

console.log(data);
```

However it doesn't seem to print all values that were not equal. What's wrong here?

I want to get new array which consists of difference between these two arrays.

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Do you expect everything from `values` **and** from `originalValues` that is not in the other, **or** only items from `values` that aren't in `originalValues` **or** only items from `originalValues` that are not in `values`?

Comment: only items from values that aren't in originalValues

Comment: @user122222 if you need values from original array then why you're concatenating both the arrays ?

Answer (score 1):

in the comment you said "only items from values that aren't in originalValues"
so try this way?

```
values.filter(i => originalValues.findIndex(v => v.interval === i.interval && v.value === i.value) === -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the object by taking a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for unwanted tuples.

```js
const getKey = keys => object => keys.map(k => object[k]).join('|');

let values = [{ id: 1, value: 2, interval: 15 }, { id: 2, value: 10, interval: 11 }, { id: 6, value: 2, interval: 12 }, { id: 5, value: 2, interval: 33 }, { id: 1, value: 33, interval: 11 }],
    originalValues = [{ id: 1, value: 2, interval: 10 }, { id: 2, value: 10, interval: 11 }, { id: 6, value: 12, interval: 12 }, { id: 5, value: 2, interval: 12 }, { id: 1, value: 33, interval: 13 }],
    key = getKey(['value', 'interval']),
    seen = new Set(originalValues.map(key)),
    result = values.filter(o => !seen.has(key(o)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -2):

you have to take all the values and, filter each of them if there is any element in originalValues array that matches criteria

```
values.filter(v=>!originalValues.some(o=>o.interval===v.interval && o.value === v.value))
```

if it's not too many items in each of them it's okay, but if you have two many items, be cautios, it loops in originalValues for every item inside values array

Comment: @onik please make an effort to explain your answer. The approach taken and why it may be better than others. Just posting a snippet of code is not ideal. Notice you've already received two down-votes for it. The more you improve it, the better the chances of it being well received.